# Visual Studio - Use custom build in CEFSharp

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, nuget, cefsharp

I had successfully built the **CEF** with `proprietary_codecs` enabled, but not getting any way to use that inside my Visual Studio project.

Below is my `binary_distrib` structure. I just made `x86 Debug-build`

[image]

Currently in my **Visual Studio (WPF C# Project)** I'm using `NuGet` for `CEFSharp`, **how I can replace the cef binary of nuget with my own built?**

> I need it cause by default CEFSharp not support any video codec so I needa use my custom built

Comment: Firstly you need to make sure you built the exact commit that was used for the CefSharp version you are using. Secondly you need to build a release version,  looks like you have a debug build. See https://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=13515&start=60#p47645 for my previous comments on how to determine the commit used.

Answer (score 0):

I am more familiar with nuget. Not sure your issue is related to nuget. As a suggestion, you should [use some scripts](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/AutomatedBuildSetup.md#markdown-header-windows-configuration),especially, `automate-git.py` command-line arguments

And also do not forget to use the system environments to include them.

You can check [this similar issue](https://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=15843) and [this document](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/MasterBuildQuickStart.md).

**Besides**, if this do not help, please contact with [CEF Forum](https://magpcss.org/ceforum/index.php).

Answer (score 0):

Well we are using the CefSharp windows forms. We also replace CEF build to enable proprietary_codecs.

After you build your CEF and you must make sure you are building a matching version for the nuget, you should get the following files (some are optional) from the folder (\chromium_git\chromium\src\out\Debug_GN_x86) ..

- locales folder
- swiftshader folder
- cef.pak
- cef_100_percent.pak
- cef_200_percent.pak
- cef_extensions.pak
- chrome_elf.dll
- d3dcompiler_47.dll
- devtools_resources.pak
- icudtl.dat
- libcef.dll
- libEGL.dll
- libGLESv2.dll
- snapshot_blob.bin
- v8_context_snapshot.bin

Copy these files to your application output folder which will replace the files from the nuget.

For our case, we have copied these files to a folder next to our project and it is included in our git repository, and in visual studio we use after build events to copy the files after each build.